Firestore struct in SwiftData
I have a @Model class like so:
@Model
final class MyModel {
    
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: String
    var firestoreStruct: FirestoreStruct
    
    init(id: String, firestoreStruct: FirestoreStruct) {
        self.id = id
        self.firestoreStruct = firestoreStruct
    }
}

FirestoreStruct is a struct with which I fetch data from Firestore:
struct FirestoreStruct: Codable {
    
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var title: String
}

My use case is to save the FirestoreStructs to fetch them from Widgets etc (but I don't even get there).
When I try to insert and save an instance of MyModel to the modelContext, I get an error

Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error:
FirebaseFirestore.FirestoreEncodingError.encodingIsNotSupported("DocumentID
values can only be encoded with Firestore.Encoder")

This is the code saving the data. However the error only gets produced when saving. When I remove the second line of code, it does postpone the crash to when minimizing the app (I assume SwiftData then tries to save it).
modelContext.insert(MyModel(id: "this is the ID", firestoreStruct: FirestoreStruct(title: "title")))
try modelContext.save()

I've set up the modelContainer correctly (as I believe)
.modelContainer(for: [MyModel.self])

How can I avoid this error?

Do the extra work and create a separate, non Firestore, type and use that in your model instead.

Isn't there a more "elegant" way with less redundant code?

Have a look at this Link1 and Link2.

The question needs clarity. It says - use case is to save the FirestoreStructs - however, the code modelContext.insert(MyModel doesn't do that; it's saving the MyModel object: which, btw is not codable and does not conform to Firebase protocols. Also, why this @Attribute(.unique) var id: String instead of using the built in Firebase @DocumentID var id: String? which is unique and auto-generating? Take a look at @peterfriese article Firebase Mapping for some pointers. Is modelContainer even needed?

I use MyModel to wrap multiple types of FirestoreDocuments into one class which I then can save. Why one class? Because the data stored in it belongs together.
You can assume, that the MyModel Class is set up correctly, instead I was wondering how to make it work with the two fields which each are FirestoreDocuments.

I am not sure what you're attempting to do is clear. The only reason to include @DocumentID var id: String? in a model is to conform that model to what firebase needs to store that model in Firestore. But it appears your storing your data in a totally separate database. So... why use Firestore at all? Or the flip side question applies as well; if you already have Firestore, why use yet-another database? It sounds like duplicate work and duplicate maintenance.

After reading some comments and trying the tips, I implemented a solution which I find quite unsatisfying.
To avoid dedicated structs (by leaving out the FirebaseID) I had to override the default en- and decoding behavior, as suggested. This lead to much boilerplate code with the potential of messing up and destroying Firebase's own fetch logic.
So after all I reversed and created non-firebase structs to encode them instead, which worked without complications.
So as far as I got to know, Firestore does not support storing it's documents in SwiftData (natively).

*Firestore does not support storing it's documents in SwiftData * - Why would you expect Firestore to store its documents in a different database? e.g. Firestore "documents" can't be stored in Couchbase, Realm or a number of others because they do not conform to those databases parameters. Likewise, you cannot store a Couchbase document in Firebase either (without adhering to the Firebase requirements). Can you clarify this answer?

@Jay FirestoreDocuments, on an abstract level, have only one difference to regular structs: @DocumentID. So when I fetch e.g. User from Firestore and I want to save that user, to speed up loading next time, I expect to be allowed to do so. Of course I might lose some abilities of FirebaseDocuments, but that is okay in my case. I just want to save the instance of User so I can access it later (e.g. to get the users first name).

I think what you said was my point. @DocumentID is specific to Firebase and only applies to Firebase objects. You cannot store it in Couchbase for example. Just like if you were to set up a Couchbase Object with a var mutableDoc = MutableDocument(id: "doc1") property. A MutableDocument is specific to Couchbase and will not store in SwiftData OR Firebase (or anywhere else) for that matter. Also, So when I fetch e.g. User from Firestore and I want to save that user, to speed up loading next time Firebase data is cached and will pull locally if it's current so it's super speedy!
